# Is it possible to use jQuery's .when without an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

http://jsfiddle.net/f4hmL/235/

```
function showData() {
    alert("boop!");
}

function method1() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(dfd.resolve(), 10000);
    return dfd.promise();
}

function method2() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(dfd.resolve(), 6000);
    return dfd.promise();
}

$.when(method1(), method2()).then(showData);​
```

I was hoping to only see "boop" displayed when both deferred objects resolved, but I see it immediately. Is it possible to achieve this? Is jQuery's "when" method the right function to be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't passing the right thing to `setTimeout()`.  This won't work because you are calling `dfd.resolve()` immediately and passing that result to `setTimeout()` in this line:

```
setTimeout(dfd.resolve(), 10000);
```

Instead, you need something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {dfd.resolve()}, 10000);
```

which will not call the resolve until the timeout fires.