# How to avoid timeout while reading rows from a query (Phonegap + Javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops, cordova, crash, timeout

I am trying to insert around 58000 rows of a query inside a string. But after the row around 8000 I get a timeout error.

I've already tried to use SetTimeout funcions but it was of no use.

Check the code that I am working on:

```
function onQuerySuccess(tx, results) {
  console.log("Entering onQuerySuccess");
  if(results.rows) {
    console.log("Rows: " + results.rows.length);
    var len = results.rows.length;

    if(len > 0) {

    store_html(results, 0);

    console.log("Finished Reading Rows: " + len);       
    saveNotes();
    console.log("Finished Saving Notes");

} else {
  //This should never happen
  console.log("No rows.");
    }
  } else {    
        alert("No records match selection criteria.");
      }
      console.log("Leaving openView");

function store_html(results, rows_complete){
   rows_complete=store_html_input(results, rows_complete);
   console.log("Returning row:" + rows_complete);

   if (rows_complete<results.rows.length)
   {
      setTimeout(store_html(results, rows_complete), 50);
   }

}

function store_html_input(results, rows_complete){
  for(var i = rows_complete; i < rows_complete+100; i++) {
            gpsTextFile = gpsTextFile + results.rows.item(i).section + ' ' +     results.rows.item(i).timestamp + ' ' +                             results.rows.item(i).latitude + ' ' +
            results.rows.item(i).longitude + ' ' + results.rows.item(i).acx + ' ' +     results.rows.item(i).acy + ' ' +
            results.rows.item(i).acz + ' ' + results.rows.item(i).speed;
            gpsTextFile = gpsTextFile + "\n\r";
  }
  return i;
}
```

So.. I get that "Javascript execution exceeded timeout".

Thank you for any of your help!

Best Regards.

Comment: Have you tried taking down the number of rows you are entering at a time?  Try like 5 or 10 and see if you still get the error.  `for(var i = rows_complete; i < rows_complete+5; i++) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `setTimeout()` to NOT execute the function immediately.  Change from this:

```
setTimeout(store_html(results, rows_complete), 50);
```

to this:

```
setTimeout(function() {store_html(results, rows_complete)}, 50);
```

As you had it before, it was immediately executing `store_html(results, rows_complete)` and passing the return value from that to `setTimeout() which was not delaying anything.  This is a common mistake ([2nd one of these problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877722/is-it-possible-to-use-jquerys-when-without-an-ajax-call/12877736#12877736) I've answered today).

Comment: jfriend00! That really did the trick! Thank you!! Do you know where can I find information about this sintax on the web?

Comment: @RickON - I'm not sure what you're asking.  `setTimeout()` takes a function reference as it's first argument as you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope). You can either pass the name of a function or you can use an anonymous function (which is what I suggested).  You can read about anonymous functions [here](http://thoughtsonscripts.blogspot.com/2012/01/javascript-anonymous-functions.html) or in many other pages you could find with a Google search for "javascript anonymous functions".